# Поиск наиболее часто встречающегося элемента в подстроке

Tags: java, алгоритм

На вход поступает строка из строчных латинских букв(до 50000 символов), количество подстрок(до 50000), а далее пары чисел, обозначающих первый и последний элемент подстроки.

Пример:

abacaba

3

1 1

1 7

2 4

На выходе получить наиболее часто встречающийся элемент в каждой подстроке:

a

a

c

Задание сдается на автоматическое тестирование на сайте. Ограничение по времени 3 сек, по памяти 512 Мбайт. На одном из тестов выдает 3.11/3 сек, тест с максимальными входными данными. Назрел только один вопрос: как можно ускорить алгоритм? По памяти вроде с большим запасом проходит, да и результат верный выдает.

```java
public class TheMostFrequentSymbol {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FastScanner in = new FastScanner(System.in);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);

        String s;
        s = in.next();
        int q;
        q = in.nextInt();
        int[] l = new int[q];
        int[] r = new int[q];
        for (int i = 0; i < q; ++i) {
            l[i] = in.nextInt();
            r[i] = in.nextInt();
        }

        char[] result = new char[q];


        for (int k = 0; k < q; k++) {
            Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
            int max = 0;
            for (int i = l[k] - 1; i < r[k]; i++) {
                char ch = s.charAt(i);
                if (map.containsKey(ch)) {
                    map.put(ch, map.get(ch) + 1);
                } else {
                    map.put(ch, 1);
                }
                if (map.get(ch) >= max) {
                    max = map.get(ch);
                    result[k] = ch;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; ++i) {
            out.println(result[i]);
        }

        out.close();
    }

    static class FastScanner {

        BufferedReader br;
        StringTokenizer st;

        FastScanner(InputStream stream) {
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        String next() {
            while (st == null || !st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                try {
                    st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return st.nextToken();
        }

        int nextInt() {
            return Integer.parseInt(next());
        }
    }
}
```

- задание с coursera.org, для самообучения

Comment: Укажите ссылку на сайт с задачей, чтобы было понятно, что она не из какого-нибудь текущего соревнования. А по поводу неизвестного теста, испытайте Ваше решение на максимальном: строка длиной 50000 и 50000 подстрок с 1 по 50000

Comment: @defaultlocale ссылку указала. А тестирование и правда на максимальных значениях, но вопрос не отпадает. Не вижу каким способ алгоритм ускорить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если `S` — длина строки, а `T` — количество подстрок, то сложность Вашего алгоритма O(T*S). В худшем случае это примерно 25*10^8 итераций.

Учитывая, что используется ограниченный набор символов, можно построить алгоритм со сложностью O(S+T).

**Предрасчет**

Для каждой буквы алфавита `I` (всего 26) и для каждого префикса длины `L` (первые `L` символов) заданной строки рассчитаем сколько раз (`lettersCount[I][L]`) буква встречается в префиксе.

Например, для строки «abacaba»:

- `lettersCount[0][5] = 3`, т.к. буква 0 («a») встречается в префиксе длины 5 («abaca») три раза;
- `lettersCount[0][0] = 0`;
- `lettersCount[0][1] = 1`;
- `lettersCount[2][8] = 1`.

Рассчитать `lettersCount` для всех возможных значений (26 букв X (S+1) возможных длин префиксов) можно одним проходом по строке.

**Подстроки**

Используем предрасчитанные значения чтобы расчитать ответ для каждой заданной подстроки (с X по Y) не пробегаясь по ней.

С помощью формулы `lettersCount[I][Y] - lettersCount[I][X-1]` можно определить сколько раз в подстроке встречается буква с индексом `I`.

Например: буква «a» встречается в подстроке с 2 по 5: `lettersCount[0][5] - lettersCount[0][1] = 3 - 1 = 2` раза.

Осталось пройтись по всем буквам и подсчитать, которая из них встречается чаще остальных.

Всего потребуется примерно 26*S + 26*Т итераций, что должно уложиться в лимит времени.

Comment: элегантное решение, плюс от меня :)